# AngularJS GET request to Flask/rest API

Tags: python, angularjs, rest

I need some help if possible. We are building an internal web application and have decided to use AngularJS. Everything has been going fine, but now we are trying to integrate/test calls to a Flask REST API. The following is my data, and is mocked up in my API.

```
machine_data = {
    "machine1": {
        "machine_name": 'LX1host',
        "machine_model": '12345678',
        "machine_serial": '87654321'
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass in a variable from my view to return the above structure. Here is the API method.

```
@app.route(v1_root_machine, methods=['GET'])
def machine_list():

    try:
        if 'hostname' in request.args:
           target = request.args['hostname']
    except:
        target = None

    machines = machine_data

    if not target:
       return general_error(error="No machines...")

    message = {"status": 200,
           "message": machines
           }

    resp = jsonify(message)
    return resp
```

I see the call come in and get a 200 on the Flask side, but I do see an error on the JS console and it states. I've been googling this but it looks like it could be several things.

```
 ConsoleAgent: Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:6:417
    at q.then.p.$resolved (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-resource.min.js:9:330)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:112:113
    at n.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:15)
    at n.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:123:106)
    at n.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:293)
    at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:81:240)
    at M (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:85:342)
    at XMLHttpRequest.F.onload (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:86:367) (url: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js) in :327
```

Here is the snippet of my view.

```
<tr ng-repeat="machine in data_table.message | filter:searchText">
 <td><a ui-sref="machineRoute({hostname: machine.hostname">machine.hostname </a></td>
```

My angular module and config.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router','ngResource','testServices']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('machineRoute', {
            url: '/machineRoute/:hostname',
            templateUrl: './machines.html',
            controller: 'machinesController'
        })
});
```

**controller:**

```
app.controller('machinesController', function ($scope, machineService) {
    $scope.data_table = MachineService.query();
});
```

**service.js**

```
    var boxServices = angular.module('boxServices', ['ngResource']);

    boxServices.factory('MachineService', ['$resource',
      function($resource){
        return   $resource('http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1.0/machineroute/:hostname',                  {hostname: "@hostname"}, {
 query: {method:'GET', params: {}, isArray:false}
    });
  }]);
```

I can also make this call with httpie which is successful so I'm pretty sure it's my angular setup, but I can't figure out how to get it to pass the variable correctly.

```
http GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1.0/machineroute/ hostname=testhost
```

this is my return packet from the httpie call.

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cont
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 1685
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 11 May 2015 22:50:41 GM
Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7

{
    "message": {
       "machine1": {
           "machine_name": 'LX1host',
           "machine_model": '12345678',
           "machine_serial": '87654321'
        }
    },
    "status": 200
}
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

So I believe we found my problem and it appears to be a simple understanding issue.

Overall it appears to be the way I was understanding the use of $scope and $stateParams. Since I was trying to work up a solution with ui-router the way I was going about it was off. from the quick reference.

```
$stateParams
A service that is populated by the current state's parameters. Useful for injecting into your own controllers or services to access the parameters. It will have one key per url parameter.

Note: it must be injected into a controller directly attached to the desired state
```

so this controller method is not right..

```
app.controller('machinesController', function ($scope, machineService) {
    $scope.data_table = MachineService.query();
});
```

using $stateParms, looks and works correctly.

```
app.controller('machinesController', function ($scope, $stateParams, machineService) {
    $scope.data_table = machineService.get({hostname:$stateParams.hostname});
});
```

then my factory I can simplify it.

```
snip..
  boxServices.factory('MachineService', ['$resource',
      function($resource){
        return   $resource('http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1.0/machineroute/:hostname',   {});
    };
..snip
```

Once these changes were made I was able to see my API get called with the correct parameter and retrieve data. In the end, read the docs(again!) and seek out help from others :)